# CASE CONVERT SETS NULL VALUE to 1/1/1900 SQL Sybase

Tags: date, null, sybase

I have 1 table with END_DATE as CHAR (8). There are either an END_DATE = some date in this format (12/31/2013) or '' or '  /  /  ' values.

how can I run a greater than on END_DATE to current date?

Example:

```
SELECT RES_CODE, END_DATE 
FROM RES_DEFS
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE ISDATE(END_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN END_DATE ELSE '12/31/2099' END) > GETDATE()
```

This where statement excludes the null values `(the ' ' values).`  Those values indicate no END_DATE and should be set as a future date but this convert sends them back to 1900!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out:

```
SELECT RES_CODE, END_DATE FROM RES_DEFS WHERE (CASE WHEN END_DATE= '' THEN '12/31/2099' WHEN ISDATE(END_DATE) = 1 then END_DATE else '12/31/2099' END) > GETDATE()
```

Comment: Don't you want to convert those to a date type as in your question? Are you sure you're not getting string comparisons?